# Problems with SQL syntax? MAX not working

Tags: php, sql, max

```
$query="SELECT title, max(postid) FROM post";
```

postid is a increasing numeric value `(1,2,3...)`. At the moment, the highest value is `49`, but It's pulling up 1. It seems to be ignoring the MAX statement.

otherwise everything else is working great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not valid syntax, which engine is running it?

You either need:

```
 SELECT title, max(postid) FROM post GROUP BY title;
```

to get multiple records, one for each title, showing the max postid for each title, or

```
SELECT max(postid) FROM post
```

to get the single max postid from the table.

If you want the highest postid and the title that goes with it, you need

```
 SELECT TOP 1 title, postid FROM post ORDER BY postid DESC
```

or

```
 SELECT title, postid FROM post ORDER BY postid DESC LIMIT 1
```

depending on your SQL engine.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using $query="SELECT title FROM post ORDER BY postid DESC LIMIT 1"; which was based on one of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing is that the field that is used in **MAX** function should be *INT Type*

Then it will give accurate result:

```
SELECT title, max(postid) FROM post GROUP BY title
```

> **Postid should be an integer.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT title, max(postid) FROM post GROUP BY title
```

I would have expected whichever sql engine you are using to respond with an error without a group by clause in your statement. However, if the GROUP BY is in some way implied somewhere else in your code, you should remove 'title' from the select clause (since I would expect a 'title' to be associated with only one post anyway). In that case if you simply expect the max postid from the post table your statement should read:

```
SELECT max(postid) FROM post
```